# Why did this fix break pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

There is [a commit on pgf](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/43b4544ac4ad12edd4943cf4dee19ce7857f8f58) that removes useless `%` at the end of lines. This commit appears to have broken pgf-plots. Why is this? User [hmenke states](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/43b4544ac4ad12edd4943cf4dee19ce7857f8f58#commitcomment-49057668)  that

> the fact that it worked previously is a bug.

and provides a fix, but I don't understand what's going on.

`%` is the marker for comments, so how could an extra `%` at the end of a line change the behavior of a program? Why did theis extra `%` cause pgf-plots to work?

Comment: This fix broke pgfplots because it stopped expanding something that was accidentally expanded previously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old version before the fixes you mention.

```
\def\tikz@expand{%
  \advance\tikz@expandcount by -1%
  \ifnum\tikz@expandcount<0\relax%
    \tikzerror{Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?}%
    \let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@finish%
  \else%
    \let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@@expand
  \fi%
  \pgfutil@next}%
```

What's the problem? When `\tikz@expand` is expanded, TeX finds (line breaks just not to produce a too long line)

```
\advance\tikz@expandcount by -1\ifnum\tikz@expandcount<0\relax
\tikzerror{Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?}
\let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@finish\else\let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@@expand\fi
\pgfutil@next
```

and its processing rules require that `\ifnum` is expanded because there might be another digit coming along. What happens? Suppose the current value of `\tikx@expandcount` is 2. Then the `\ifnum` test returns false and TeX sees

```
\advance\tikz@expandcount by -1\else\let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@@expand\fi
\pgfutil@next
```

Note that the `\advance` instruction is still pending. Now `\else is expanded and TeX sees

```
\advance\tikz@expandcount by -1\let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@@expand\fi
\pgfutil@next
```

No digit comes along and the `\advance` instruction is finalized. Then TeX proceeds with

```
\let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@@expand\fi\pgfutil@next
```

Suppose, on the contrary, that the value of `\tikz@expand` is 0. The `\ifnum` test will return ***false***, because the `\advance` instruction hasn't been finalized yet. The wrong path would be followed! Indeed `\pgfutil@next` would become `\tikz@@expand` instead of the wanted `\tikz@finish` after the error message.

How to correctly write that code?

```
\def\tikz@expand{%
  \advance\tikz@expandcount by -1
  \ifnum\tikz@expandcount<0
    \tikzerror{Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?}%
    \let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@finish
  \else
    \let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@@expand
  \fi
  \pgfutil@next
}
```

Note that I removed the useless `\relax`, which can be simply replaced with a space (the endline). The rule when TeX is looking for a number is that the search for digits proceeds with macro expansion and ends when something unexpandable that's not a digit is found. A space is not a digit and TeX will gobble it (it won't gobble any other token in the same situation).

Using `%` characters in other places (where I removed them) denotes poor command of TeX's syntax rules.

Answer (score 2):

The end of the line is in this context space for TeX. When there is space after a number, TeX knows that it is a point to stop reading the number parameter (well, `\relax` is a stronger option). In the other case, TeX may assume that also the next command is, e.g., a part of the argument.

Comment: Thank you. And how is the `%` at the end of the line interpreted?

Comment: @usernumber It comments out everything, including the end of the line (which in this case cannot be interpreted as space).